# Using numpy arrays with lpsolve?

Tags: python, numpy, lpsolve

In the docs, it says you can use numpy arrays:

> numpy package
>
> In the above section Maximum usage of matrices with lpsolve the
> package numpy was already mentioned. See [Link](https://numpy.org/) for a
> brief overview. This package is the successor of the older and
> obsolete package Numeric. Since lp_solve is all about arrays and
> matrices, it is logical that the lpsolve Python driver accepts numpy
> arrays. This is possible from driver version 5.5.0.9. Before it was
> needed that numpy arrays were converted to lists. For example:

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> from lpsolve55 import *
>>> lp=lpsolve('make_lp', 0, 4);
>>> c = array([1, 3, 6.24, 0.1])
>>> ret = lpsolve('set_obj_fn', lp, c)
```

> Note that the numpy array variable c is passed directly to lpsolve.
> Before driver version 5.5.0.9 this gave an error since lpsolve did not
> know numpy arrays. They had to be converted to lists:

```
>>> ret = lpsolve('set_obj_fn', lp, list(c))
```

> That is ok for small models, but for larger arrays this gives an extra
> memory overhead since c is now two times in memory. Once as the numpy
> array and once as list.
>
> Note that all returned arrays from lpsolve are always lists.
>
> Also note that the older package Numeric is not supported by lpsolve.
> So it is not possible to provide a Numeric array to lpsolve. That will
> give an error.

http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/Python.htm

When I attempt to do that I get an error.

```
lp = lpsolve('make_lp', 0, 7)
coef = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
lpsolve('set_obj_fn', lp, coef)
```

Results in:

```
lpsolve('set_obj_fn', lp, coef)
lpsolve.error: invalid vector.
```

If I would do:

```
lpsolve('set_obj_fn', lp, coef.tolist())
```

It works but costs much more memory (in the general case).

When I run `lpsolve()`

It results in:

```
lpsolve  Python Interface version 5.5.0.9
using lpsolve version 5.5.2.0
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in the `dtype` of the array - to test, try `coef = np.array([0.0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])`

Comment: You are probably right. Had the same problem previously with ints. :) Checking right now. Many thanks for your input.

Comment: I can't test right now because I don't have `lpsolve` at work. If what I proposed works, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: `coef = np.array([0.0, 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.], dtype=np.float32)` I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PyLPSolve if you are having trouble with lpsolve. It is a wrapper for lpsolve that allowed me to use numpy arrays.

http://www.stat.washington.edu/~hoytak/code/pylpsolve/